# no css3 color transition with @font-face on chrome/safari

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, safari, css-transitions

I'm using a webfont embedded with @font-face and getting no css color transition (just plain old instant change on hover) in chrome and safari. Things go well in Firefox though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide code? (Use some tool like jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I'm guessing your text is a link. Webkit has a bug where visited links do not animate.

Comment: You're right: I had the same issue and it turned out to be the :visited links. It's fixed in the latest  version of Canary (20.0.1089.0) though. Here's the bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101245